# What is context of function called inside another function without this?

Tags: javascript

I have code where `LivingBeing` is superType and `Man` is subType. I have defined `toString()` methods on both of them. Consider the code below:

```
function LivingBeing() {}

LivingBeing.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "hi";
};

function Man() {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Man.prototype, LivingBeing.prototype);
Man.prototype.toString = function () {
    return window.toString(); 
};


let m1 = new Man();
console.log(m1.toString()); // Prints [object Window]
```

But if I remove the `window` context :

```
function LivingBeing() {}

LivingBeing.prototype.toString = function () {
    return "hi";
};

function Man() {}
Object.setPrototypeOf(Man.prototype, LivingBeing.prototype);
Man.prototype.toString = function () {
    return toString(); // Window context removed now; Rest code same
};


let m1 = new Man();
console.log(m1.toString()); // Prints [object Undefined]
```

Should not the absence of context be taken as window by the browser ? Whose `toString()` is it calling ?

Comment: Object.prototype.toString()

Comment: Still the same `window.toString` (cause it’s the only globally exposed thing of that name), just this time called without `window` as its context due to how you called it. You could omit all that class stuff to demonstrate that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should not the absence of context be taken as window by the browser?

No, because the native [`toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString) method (inherited by the global object from `Object.prototype`) is a strict mode function, and does not fall back to the global object when no context is passed.

Comment: I am not able to understand what you mean by `native toString` method ? I mean which object  `toString()` is it calling ?

Comment: @Number945 It's still calling `window.toString()` (isn't that what you were trying to do?), as all properties of `window` are available in the global scope. It's just that you're now using it like `window.toString.call(undefined)`, or `const f = window.toString; f()`

Comment: I did not find it documented that `toString` is strict mode method. How did you find it ?

Comment: @Number945 [ECMAScript §9.3](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-built-in-function-objects) says "*Built-in functions that are ECMAScript function objects must be strict functions.*" And also none of the steps in the spec does apply the sloppy-mode behaviour, [it exists](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/#sec-ordinarycallbindthis) only for user-defined functions.