# Unable to destructure map function from array. Why?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

I'm trying to use destructuring to extract the map function from an array. The method seems to be destructured correctly. But I get the following error when I try to use it:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.map called on null or undefined
```

Shouldnt it be able to access the array using its scope?

```js
const array = [1,2,3,4]
const {map} = array
console.log({map})
map(x => x*x) // Uncaught TypeError: Array.prototype.map called on null or undefined
```

Comment: The destructuring is fine. The problem is that when you call `map` like that, `this` within the call is either `undefined` (in strict mode -- which you seem to be using [good!]) or the global object (in loose mode), neither of which is your array. :-) You'd have to do `map.call(array, x => x * x)` to set `this` correctly. Or use `bind` (in which case you probably wouldn't use destructuring, `const map = array.map.bind(array);`) Details in the linked question.

Comment: Why dont you simply use array.map(x => x*x) ?

Comment: @David - Presumably there's more to the actual problem the OP is solving, but it wasn't relevant to the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder All builtin methods are implicitly strict, so `map` never defaults to the global object.

Comment: @Bergi - Do you know, I'm not sure I ever ran across that before. A quick experiment sez: seems to be true. Thanks! Do you know where that is in the spec? I kicked around a bit but didn't find it in ~5 minute so searching. Seems like the kind of thing they'd want to list [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-strict-mode-code). (You know how I am, I like to see the spec text...) :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder https://stackoverflow.com/a/60288194/1048572 says it's in the "built-in function objects" section

Comment: @Bergi - Yup, [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-built-in-function-objects): *"Built-in functions that are ECMAScript function objects must be strict functions."*